# Print passed argument to pthread_create

Tags: c, multithreading

I want to print the passed to `create_thread` argument. I create an array with 10 `int`'s to simulate the number of each thread -

```
void* thr_func(void *arg){

printf("\nTHREAD ID %d", *(int*)arg);
return 0;

}


int main(){
int arr[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

pthread_t thread_id;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &thr_func,&arr[i]);
}
return 0;

}
```

Here is the output from two runs
1:

```
THREAD ID 1
THREAD ID 5
THREAD ID 6
THREAD ID 2
THREAD ID 3
THREAD ID 4
TTHREAD ID 0
THREAD ID 3
```

2:

```
THREAD ID 1
THREAD ID 2
THREAD ID 5
THREAD ID 6
THREAD ID 3
THREAD ID 7
THREAD ID 4
THREAD ID 8
THREAD ID 8
```

I know I can't rely on consecutive numbers, but why does it print some of them twice ?

Comment: Buffering issues? Also note that output to `stdout` is by default *line-buffered*, meaning the output buffer will be flushed on a newline. That's why you should always put newlines *last* in your output.

Comment: Also note that your process might exit before all threads have started running, or before they are finished. That will kill all threads.

Comment: If I put sleep for one second, all 10 numbers are printed, but without sleep and newlines in the end, still some are printed twice

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think waiting on the child threads for their termination should work (`pthread_join`)?

Comment: Then it's most likely a buffering issues when the process ends. Perhaps something like this: In your example the thread 8 have filled the buffer and it have been printed, but then the process ends before the buffer is cleared, and when the process ends the buffer is flushed (and printed!) so you see that line again.

Comment: @Alan Yes, waiting for the threads (in a second loop) is definitely the right thing to do. Always (unless detaching the threads of course, but then the process should still not plain end).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so that should be the answer to the `OP's` question tho.

Comment: @FelixPalmen creating array of pthread_t and passing a different one each time works! I definitely dont understand why

Comment: @loannnlo I didn't find any evidence so far, therefore deleted this comment. But I'm not sure what a `pthreads` implementation is allowed to put inside a `pthread_t`. If the argument pointer might be stored there, that would be a simple explanation.

Comment: @loannnlo anyways, you'll need all those `pthread_t`s for properly joining the threads when they finished.

Comment: @loannnlo The "duplicate output" is a bug in glibc (see the linked duplicate). Simple fix is to call `pthread_exit(0);` at the end of main so that only main thread exits. This way you wouldn't need `pthread_join` or have to store pthread_t ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Some programmer dude mentioned, you should always wait for the termination of your single `child threads` in your `main` function (except you detach your threads). The reason `why` some of your `array`elements are printed twice or more often is because before your buffer is cleared the `thread` may gets killed. (In your case the `thread 8`). To avoid that the processes are shut-down before they have finished their work you have to `wait`for your threads, or in other words you have to join your threads.

**That is done by adding the function**:   `pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retvalue);`

> The pthread_join() function waits for the thread specified by thread to terminate.

Just put it in a separate `loop`after your `pthread_create() function` and the parent `thread` (main) will wait for his childs.

**Edit:**
To wait for each `thread` you could change your `pthread_t`variable to an array of threads: `pthread_t thread[10]` so you could wait for each thread in relation to the index.

```
int arr[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
pthread_t thread[10];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &thr_func,&arr[i]);
}

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    pthread_join(thread[i],NULL);
}
```

Comment: Also it's worth to mention that each thread must have it own `pthread_t` variable.

Comment: @4386427 that was my **guess** as well, but can you provide some evidence for that?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Well evidence... hmmm, I don't know but the variable hold the information for identifying the individual thread. So overwriting the value when creating the next thread will make you loose the handle to the thread.

Comment: @4386427 sure, but that alone isn't enough for a **must** -- or do you mean "*in order to use `pthread_join()`*"?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Not sure if this quote from a man page is sufficient as evidence: "Before returning, a successful call to pthread_create() stores the ID
       of the new thread in the buffer pointed to by thread; this identifier
       is used to refer to the thread in subsequent calls to other pthreads
       functions."

Comment: The simpliest solution would be to create a `pthread` array and wait for each thread in relation to the index.

Comment: @FelixPalmen yes. `pthread_join` is one function that requires the variable but there are other pthread functions than join that requires it. To me overwriting the pthread_t variable for a running thread is similar to overwriting a pointer to dynamic allocated memory or a file pointer.

Comment: @4386427 I understand your point, but both of them aren't forbidden. OP said the duplicates went away by not reusing the `pthread_t`s. A simple explanation would be the threading library stores the argument pointer there, creating a race condition when the thread isn't scheduled immediately. This would be an error if it isn't explicitly forbidden to reuse a `pthread_t` of a running thread.

Comment: @FelixPalmen my answer is right? should solve OP's question. Doesn't it?

Comment: @FelixPalmen The problem does **not** go away simply by not reusing `pthread_t`. The `pthread_join` is also required.

Comment: @4386427 yes so why doesn`t my answer get upvoted? Is there anything which is not correct?

Comment: @alan I'm not sure about the correctness of the explanation in the start of your answer. Therefore I can't vote. But the last part (i.e. under the edit) do seem correct to me.

Comment: @4386427 I think it should be upvoted tho. but yes no problem. :), I am here to help not for the rep.

Comment: @4386427 see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51612987/print-passed-argument-to-pthread-create?noredirect=1#comment90191468_51612987), it suggests otherwise.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I did read that comment. Maybe the timing of OPs system made it work for OP but on my system it also fails with an array of pthread_t In other words the `join` is required.

Comment: It would be interesting to check the code to see if there is a null check on the threadId pointer.  It's not uncommon for pointer arguments to be ignored if set to null, eg. if a threadId is not required.  The available documentation does not say there is, nor that there is not, (so, of course, you have to assume there is not).  In many cases, there would be a big design problem if the lifetime of the the threadId store had to be the same as the thread, especially if detaching a new thread somewhere in a library/subsystem - it would be a really nasty contraint.

Comment: 'you have to waitfor your threads, or in other words you have to join your threads' - or ensure that their work is complete in some other manner.